# rawurlencode not encoding white spaces

Tags: php

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
print ('href="files/'.rawurlencode($projectDesc).'/'.rawurlencode($file["FILENAME"]).'.pdf#zoom=100&view=Fit&pagemode='.$file["MODE"].'&page='.$file["PAGE"].'" class="pdfselector" target="_blank">');
```

the `$file["FILENAME"]` variable often has white-space in it, when I use plain old `urlencode()` it converts my white spaces to `+`symbols. However this is not appropriate outside the querystring so I switched to `rawurlencode()` which now appears to ignore white space all together.

Here is an example output of my `rawurlencode()`:

```
eHealth flyer_Final
```

notice how it completely ignores the white space, anyone got any ideas as to why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/44af2.php

```
<?php 
$projectDesc = "eHealth flyer_Final"; 
$file["FILENAME"] = "eHealth flyer_Final"; 
$file["MODE"] = "test"; 

print ('href="files/'.rawurlencode($projectDesc).'/'.rawurlencode($file["FILENAME"]).'.pdf#zoom=100&view=Fit&pagemode='.$file["MODE"].'&page='.$file["PAGE"].'" class="pdfselector" target="_blank">');
```

Comment: Yeh, just realised that firefox strips `%20` from the url string and replaces it with a whitespace even when just hovering links. When I actually delve into the source it is working, silly me.